# getting undefined value of coupon from data base?

Tags: php, ajax

I getting undefined value when I try to get the value of coupon from coupons table from my DB but when I get the value of percentage or price it comes correct the code is written in ajax as I am new to ajax help me solve this problem.

```
(function() {

    var path = "{{ route('validate.coupon') }}";
    $('.reserve-button').click(function() {
        var coupon_number = $('.coupon-number').val();
        var org_price = parseInt($('#amount').val());
        //alert(coupon_number);

        if (coupon_number == '') {
            alert("Please Enter Coupon Number");
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                url: path,
                data: {
                    "coupon_number": coupon_number
                },
                type: 'get',
                success: function(result) {

                    if (result.percentage == 0 && result.price == 0) {
                        alert('Sorry Coupon Not Exists');
                    } else {
                        $("input[name='coupon']").prop('disabled', true);
                        $("#btn-apply-now").remove()
                        var disc = org_price * (result.percentage / 100.0) + result.price;
                        var new_price = org_price - disc;


                        $('.price').html('$' + new_price);
                        //  $('#amount').val(new_price);
                        $('#coupon-number').val(coupon_number);
                        alert('!!__ Congratulations you got ' + result.percentage + '% and ' + result.price + '$ discount __!!');
                        $('#price_detail').append('<li class="item clearfix"><div class="title">Discount</div><span>$' + disc + '</span></li>')


                    }

                }
            });
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: already try `console.log(result);` ? it's shown the value or not? what dataType you return?

Comment: @illuminarch nothing has shown?

Comment: what data type you return when call the data? json or what?

Comment: @illuminarch see the code above?

Comment: let me know your php code

Comment: it is getting coupon number from input tag and validating through ajax

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you get the percentage, price from coupon code input and using ajax select the db.

What you need is return the json from sql response like this:

Press F12 -> Console log to check the result.
You can check in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dianeryanto/k1fd0ct7/)

```js
var coupon = 'asd';

$.ajax({
    url : "https://api.myjson.com/bins/95yl8",
    type: "get",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {coupon_code: coupon},
    success: function(res)
    { 
      console.log('all result', res);
      console.log('percentage', res['data']['percentage']);
      
    },
    error:function(x,e) {
        if(e=='parsererror') {
            alert('Error.\nParsing JSON Request failed.');
        } else if(e=='timeout'){
            alert('Request Time out.');
        } else {
            alert('Unknow Error.\n'+x.responseText);
        }
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: my example or yours?

Comment: my example :/ :(

Comment: that's why i ask your php code, but you didn't show me. You must know, im will not steal your code, i just want to look what's wrong. if you dont want to give the code, yap its good, you can solve the problem with ur self and its good for improving self learning. and when you success solve the problem you get "ya, i'm do it"

Comment: <!-- here coupn--><div "class="r-return-block"><div class="stripe-form-" style="float:left"><div class='form-row'><div class='col-xs-12 form-group card required'><input autocomplete='off' class='form-control coupon-number' placeholder="Discount Coupon" style="width: 150%; height: 40px; " size='20' type='text' name="coupon" required > </div></div></div><div id="btn-apply-now" class="form-group" style="margin-right: 0px;margin-left: -76px;margin-bottom: 0px;"><div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-0" > <a  class="wheel-btn style-2 reserve-button" style="float: right;"> Apply Now</a></div></div></div

Comment: what you return after select db? already json encode make json like my [example](https://api.myjson.com/bins/95yl8)?

Comment: when coupon is correct it return exact value of percentage and price but coupon from database it say NaN and if i insert invalid coupon  it assign NaN to price and percentage

Comment: where your php code when select to ur db? Give me code when you post/get from ajax and select the DB

Comment: visit this link make reservation then submit then select then you will come on last page coupon is added enter any invalid number you will get what i am facing http://itugolfwear.com

Comment: basically i am .net developer php is new to me :/ my boss want me to do that :/

Comment: i think the problem is when you post data from ajax and select the db its why i ask you code to check, all programming language having same logic just different syntax, idc what developer you are. where's your code when post & select DB?